# Strip whitespace in a UITextRange

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextview

I am working with a `UITextView` and am trying to programmatically change the selection so that it contains no leading or trailing whitespace, akin to `String.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespace)`.

[image: Before and After]

My approach would be to locate the outermost non-whitespace characters within the region, and then have the appropriate checks to make sure that the region is not empty or reversed. (But I have no idea how to go about this.)

```
textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: 'position of first non-whitespace character after textRange.start',
                                                to:   'position of first non-whitespace character before textRange.end')
```

Or perhaps there is a better approach, maybe using the `UITextView`’s tokenizer? In fact, the original selection range that I am trying to strip is acquired by

```
textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(position, with: .paragraph, inDirection: UITextLayoutDirection.left.rawValue)
```

however I don't want the trailing newline engulfed by `UITextGranularity.paragraph` to be included in the range.